# What determines who is shown in the ending kill cam?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

In COD WWII, every game ending kill game seems to be random.  In previous COD titles, it was the last kill of the game.  Now, I can't tell what is used to determine who is shown in the ending kill cam.  The kill cam always displays "Bronze Star Awarded for Heroic Service."

What determines who is shown in the ending kill cam?  I know it's not whoever has the highest score and it's not always the last kill of the game.

Comment: Maybe they went for some kind of POTG thing instead of being the very last kill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final killcam in WW2 displays the "best play of the match", instead of the last kill. So, if someone had some crazy killfeed, that will most likely be the final killcam. It basically shows the highlight of that match.

As for "how" the best play is determined, I think it picks the highest accumulation of points at any given time as a result of kills gained. You know, the yellow-points-sum at the right-bottom of the screen that goes up after each kill in succession.

Source:
http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-09-01-how-call-of-duty-ww2s-new-play-of-the-game-works

I quote:

> "This is awarded to the player who, regardless of the winning faction,
>   exhibits the top performance in the match. Factors for a player's
>   consideration for the Bronze Star include score-driven events like
>   kills, objectives, and Division skill use." - co-founder Michael
>   Condrey, Sledgehammer.

So kills in succession (like getting a quad feed) could very well be considered to be a Bronze Star. Or like maybe having multiple "Avenger" kills or something like that. So from what I understand of "score-driven events" it does look at the accumulated score of an instance (so for example, if you had 3 kills in a row, you would have +300 as your accumulated score (in TDM, for example), and if there was no higher accumulated score in that match than yours, then you would be rewarded with the Bronze Star).

Comment: added a website as source

Answer (score 2):

So far it has been worked out to depend on each mode, for example the 'bronze star' / POTG in TDM prioritises Headshots. I can support this claim with evidence, as in a TDM game I had a triple glide bomb kill but the 'bronze star' at the end was giving to a sniper head shot, 1 single sniper kill nothing more.

Also there is this quoted from reddit:
"It's very game mode dependant. TDM favors multiple headshots, FFA looks for the higher multi Kill, dom and hardpoint go off of the higher multi Kill with a preference for people on the obj, search just shows the last kill."

(https://www.reddit.com/r/WWII/comments/7axw45/play_of_the_game/)

Comment: I've actually noticed (now that you mention it) that a lot of the time headshots are in the ending kill cam.

Comment: Yeah almost always a headshot kill in tdm